# Plotting lines in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to make this graph with ggplot, ordering the graph by the variable "t" in ascending order, distinguishing each "t" according to status (black or white circle, it can be another marker...) and if possible the variable "id " on the ordinate axis.

```
Id<- c(1,2,3,4)
t<- c(10,5,20,15)
status<- c(0,1,0,1)
df<- data.frame(Id, t, status)
```

[image]

Comment: It's a little hard to tell exactly what you're looking for, but I think the `forcats` package can help you with ordering you t variable. You can specify a shape aesthetic in `geom_point(aes(shape = status))` to have the shape correspond to the `status` variable then use `scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 16))` to specify hollow/filled circles as the two shapes to use.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want something like this using `geom_segment` for the lines with `geom_vline` for the vertical lines. Using `shape` and `fill` aesthetics to fill the points with "black" and "white" per status. You can use the following code:

```r
Id<- c(1,2,3,4)
t<- c(10,5,20,15)
status<- c(0,1,0,1)
df<- data.frame(Id, t, status)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df %>%
  mutate(Id = as.factor(Id),
         status = as.factor(status)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = t, y = fct_reorder(Id, t, .desc = TRUE), shape = status, fill = status)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = t, y = Id, yend = Id)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(t),linetype="dotted", alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 21), name = "shapes!") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "white")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 25)) + 
  labs(x = "", y = "Id") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works perfectly. I want it for putting a dataset in format time at origen (in survival analysis).